# implementing find_or_create_by when find involves single attribute but create involves multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails app I want to find a user by their email, or if the user does not exist, create one with that email as well as a few other attributes. Is there a less clunky way than the code below to do this, perhaps using `find_or_create_by`?

```
def set_user
  if self.user = User.find_by(email: recipient)
  else
    self.user = User.create(email: recipient,
                        password: Devise.friendly_token.first(6),
                        confirmed_at: DateTime.now)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[find_or_create_by](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) takes a block that will be applied only on create.  It'll look for a record by the attribute you provide and if none is found, will create one with the block attributes you specify.

In your case this would look like:

```
user = User.find_or_create_by(email: recipient) do |user|
  user.password = Devise.friendly_token.first(6),
  user.confirmed_at = DateTime.now
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def set_user
  user = User.find_or_initialize_by(email: recipient)
  user.update( password: Devise.friendly_token.first(6),
               confirmed_at: DateTime.now) if user.new_record?
  user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Always find the user, ask if your search exists or the find method returned nil, if it returned nil then create a User

```
def set_user
user = User.find_by(email: recipient)
unless user
 user = User.create(email: recipient,
                    password: Devise.friendly_token.first(6),
                    confirmed_at: DateTime.now)
end
```